How pass all grafana session to my plugin App
How pass all grafana session cookies to my plugin App for authentication user?
I write a plugin App for make easier user for build dashboard, queries and alert management, but I have a problem for dedicated which one user build this dashboard, and access to them to see dashboard!
I pass user info in front-end to solve problem but it's not safe!
If another send self data in posted data can access to other users!
